# Can I include hardcoded data in a SQL SELECT result set?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

I have the following code:  (pseudo code)

```
Select id, name, code, address from users
```

I json encode the data from the database like so:

```
{"id":"228","name":"Jimmy","code":"12345","address":"abc street"},      {"id":"229","name":"John","code":"22345","address":"10 1st street"}
```

But I actually need the data to look like this:

```
{"id":"228","name":"Jimmy","code":"12345","address":"abc street", "DT_RowId": "row_228"},       {"id":"229","name":"John","code":"22345","address":"10 1st street","DT_RowId": "row_229"}
```

where DT_RowId is a field that has the record id, prefixed with the text "row_". 
Is there a way to force the sql statement to include this as a part of the result set? 
It might not be the best way... but the question popped into my head and so now I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the concatenation operator `||` with a string literal:

```
Select 
  id, 
  'row_' || id as DT_RowId, 
  name, 
  code, 
  address 
from users
```

Comment: And if you have a column called [id] which contains arbitrary data, use `rowid` instead, if you want the SQLite-assigned row id.